# How to make polars read database by stream

Tags: python-polars

I'm learning to use polars instead of pandas. But I encountered a problem, how to let polars read the database streamingly or how to control the size of each read. I may have a lot of data and it cannot be loaded completely into the memory at one time. I need to read it in multiple times. I tried to use the batch_size of the read_database method, but it seems that it still loads everything into the memory. There seems to be no way to implement read_database_uri with connectorx. Is there any way to solve this problem?

this my env

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
connectorx = "^0.3.2"
polars = {extras = ["connectorx", "pyarrow", "xlsx2csv"], version = "^0.19.3"}
sqlalchemy = "^2.0.21"
pymysql = "^1.1.0"
notebook = "^7.0.4"
```

some code what i writed

```py
# engine create with sqlalchemy
with engine.connect() as conn:
    query = text('select * from my_table')
    with conn.execution_options(stream_results=True).execute(query) as cursor:
        while True:
             res = cursor.fetchmany(chunk_size)
             df = pl.DataFrame(res)
```

How to use pl.read_database or pl.read_database_uri with batch_size to implement this?

--------- This code is wrong-----------

some code what i writed:

```py
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    query = 'select * from users'

    df = pl.read_database(query=query, connection=cursor, batch_size=1000)
    for i in df.groupby(by='age'):
        print(type(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `batch_size` is not meant to replicate something like a lazyframe. Regardless of the setting, it's going to load everything in memory. The use case for tweaking that is if your database has low memory and needs small batches or if your connection times out with bigger batches.

Your best bet is likely to take advantage of the database's ability to split up data.

Instead of:

```
query = 'select * from users'

df = pl.read_database(query=query, connection=cursor, batch_size=1000)
for i in df.groupby(by='age'):
    print(type(i))
```

maybe:

```
agesdf=pl.read_database("select distinct age from users", cursor)
for age in agesdf['age']:
    subdf=pl.read_database(f"select col1, col2, col3 from users where age={age},
                           cursor)
    print(type(subdf))
```

Another approach may be to take a local backup of your users table as a local dataset and then you can use lazy evaluation against that.

The right solution is going to be dependent on your data and what you're trying to ultimately achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's uesful. I want to  use 'limit xxx offset xx', because my task likes ETL, many data in queue to wash, but it seems like can't do that. How to do that? like get data first and pl.Dataframe?

Comment: I'm really sure what you mean. What is preventing you from using limit offset? You can certainly do that instead of my for loop construction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time. I know what is my error now. I gave a wrong code for this question. I want to ask how to use cursor with batch_size, like my new code. Because  the pl doc is a bit difficult for me to understand. I apologize to you again